# Whatsapp Business API Developer not working

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, whatsapp, whatsapi

I was tring to configure and setup the developer environment of a single instance of the WhatsApp Business API.I had finished **#Step 5** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance#step-5--verify-containers-are-running and the docker is running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH6Fr.png)

Whenever I try to call https://localhost:9090 in browser but the error is  "This site can’t be reached".
then i used the command `docker-compose logs`,the error is `MySQL is not up yet - sleeping` and `getaddrinfo for host "db" port 3306: Name or service not known`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqd2t.png)
Here is db.env code

```
WA_DB_ENGINE=MYSQL
WA_DB_HOSTNAME=db
WA_DB_PORT=3306
WA_DB_USERNAME=root
WA_DB_PASSWORD=testpass
WA_DB_CONNECTION_IDLE_TIMEOUT=180000
```

So anyone have idea please, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In db name you must put the address that the docker container will have.

run command
iptables -L -n
[image]

db.env file

```
WA_DB_ENGINE=MYSQL
WA_DB_HOSTNAME=172.17.0.2
WA_DB_PORT=3306
WA_DB_USERNAME=userName
WA_DB_PASSWORD=Pass123
WA_DB_CONNECTION_IDLE_TIMEOUT=180000
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Pass123
     MYSQL_USER: userName
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: Pass123
```

Answer (score -1):

System is not able to resolve "db" to your mysql container.
Use the name of the mysql container in WA_DB_HOSTNAME.
Alternatively, point "db" to the correct mysql container by making /etc/hosts entry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).